# identification SMD 3 Pin 3x1.5mm code 4B C39 for stereo camera

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount, telephone, stereo

I am trying to build stereo camera using android or iphones. The pcb is from a wired selfie stick and works well. By using 2 pcb's with one push button, simultaneous photos can be taken. I have looked at the SMD code book and think the device is a sot23 BC8598 but frankly not sure.pcb is 1 button and 1 smd.
The pcb is attached to the phone with a 4 pole 3.5mm audio jack, it emulates the volume control of an earphone with mic.
If someone could point me to an explanation as to why this works and all the resisters I have used haven't I would be grateful.
Yours hopefully
Steve

[image: selfie stick pcb]

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a simple part- despite the simple package it is a complex CMOS chip designed specifically for this task. I doubt it will be easily possible to find the manufacturer, though if you search around in Chinese language it should be possible.